# Обрезка строки php

Tags: php

Простенький вопрос, но не могу сформулировать для гугла
есть строка `number_id=1`, она может быть `number_id=100` или `number_id=10`
мне нужно получить числовые значения, т.е. `1`, `100`, `10`

пытаюсь так, но не выходит

```
<?php 
$temp = $prod['var'];
$test = explode("=",$temp); 
print $temp;
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php

Comment: я читал документацию, спасибо, но мне не помогло

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков и что получаете в $temp? может $temp[1] ?

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков как делал, что не помогло? получается массив с индексом 0 и 1... в 0 - имя в 1 - значение....... что конкретно лежит в `$prod['var']` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский дак выводит исходную строку, вот и не получается

Answer (score 1):

Почти верно все сделал. Вот так надо

```
<?php 
    $temp = $prod['var'];
    $test = explode("=",$temp); 
    print $test[1];
?>
```

Comment: а лучше `list(,$id) = ...` и `echo $id`. Ну не то чтобы лучше, но как более читабельный вариант с именованием переменных

Comment: @teran не лучше и не четабильнее, имхо)